# Suppose $A$ knows $a$ and $B$ knows $b$, is it possible to efficiently compute $g^{ab}$ without leaking $g^a$ and $g^b$ to each other?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, multiparty-computation

I know the garbled circuit solution, but is there any more efficient method?

Comment: Isn't that exactly Diffie-Hellman?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible because if $B$ knows $b$ and $g^{ab}$, then she can compute $\left(g^{ab}\right)^{b^{-1} \bmod N} = g^a$ (where $N$ is the order of $g$, which is normally prime so that $b^{-1} \bmod N$ exists).

*EDIT:* As noted by poncho in the comments, this assumes we are in a typical discrete logarithm setting, where the order of the group is prime to avoid attacks on the discrete logarithm by Pohlig-Hellman. In other settings such as RSA it may not be feasible to compute $N$ in the first place, but on the other hand having a group of non-prime order makes the discrete logarithm easier to attack...

Comment: @phan: It would be possible if we're doing the computation modulo a composite with unknown factorization

Comment: @poncho: Would you explain it a bit more? In my opinion, as fkraiem said, we only need $b^{-1} \mod N$. Even if $N=pq$ as in RSA, $gcd(b,N)$ basically equals 1.

Comment: @phan $N$ is the order of $g$, this is *not* $pq$ in RSA, it is a divisor of $(p-1)(q-1)$.

Comment: So it means if we use a group that can compute $g^{ab}$  without leaking $g^a$ (as poncho said, a group with an unfactorizable composite order ), then we may under the risk of cracking?

Comment: You have two somewhat conflicting requirements: you want that it be difficult to compute $g^a$ when knowing $b$ and $g^{ab}$, this is essentially the RSA problem; but you also want it to be difficult to compute $a$ knowing $g$ and $g^a$ (otherwise there's no point in doing a DH in the first place), this is the discrete log problem. For the RSA problem to be difficult, the order of the group must be composite and difficult to factor, so that it is impossible to invert $b$, but on the other hand a group of composite order is suboptimal for the discrete log...

Comment: Actually, you want $g^a$ to not be revealed at all, so it should not be public as it is in standard DH. Why can't $A$ and $B$ just exchange a random value in the first place, without going through this "pseudo-DH"?